# simdJson How to use simdJson in iOS program?(objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

simdjson is really fast, I want to use it in my project to replace NSJSONSerialization,but I dont know how to tranform ParsedJson to NSDictionary.

```
    std::string jsn = [jsonStr UTF8String];
   ParsedJson pj;
        bool a = pj.allocateCapacity(jsn.size());
        if (!a) {
            return;
        }
        const int res = json_parse(jsn, pj);
//        std::cout <<pj.tape[0];
        if (res != 0) {
            std::cout << "Error parsing:" << simdjson::errorMsg(res) << std::endl;

        }
        else {
            ParsedJson::iterator pjh(pj);
            if (!pjh.isOk()) {
                return;
            }
            compute_dump(pjh);
        }
```